# Pandoc converting dict

Tags: python, pandoc, pypandoc

I am trying to convert an XML file to MarkDown but I can't find an example of converting a python dict. Here is my code:

```
import pypandoc
import xmltodict 
import json 

datadict = open("/home/.../FIX44.xml") 
dic = xmltodict.parse(datadict.read()) 

jsondump = json.dumps(dic) 
#print jsondump 

output = pypandoc.convert(jsondump, 'md', format='json', outputfile = 'test.md') 
assert output == ""
```

When I try to run this I get:

> RuntimeError: Pandoc died with exitcode "1" during conversion

Comment: I think importing `pypandoc as pd`  is a bit confusing. `pd` is usually reserved for `pandas`...

Comment: Thanks @CIsForCookies, I'm new to Python, will correct and reserve it in the future

Comment: You cannot take any XML file, convert it to some JSON and expect that to be a representation of pandoc's internal document model. You should probably post a part of that XML file, but you'll most probably have to write a script that converts it to HTML or similar, before you can use pandoc to convert it to markdown.